# Archiving partition and removing the file group used for the same partition

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have created the below partition:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pf_table (DATETIME) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES('2018-01-01')

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pf_table_Archive (DATETIME) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES()

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ps_table AS PARTITION pf_table TO 
([primary],fg_2018_1)

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ps_table_Archive AS PARTITION pf_table_Archive TO ([primary])
```

A job runs monthly to create new partitions. I have created partitions for four months. Initially, I have only one file group. File groups and file are created first and then assigned to the partitions:

[image]

After deleting partitions which are older than 10 months from current date, I am getting the below result:

[image]

As per the requirements, I need to remove the file group along with partition. But the boundary `2018-03-01` is now assigned to the file group `fg_table_2018_1`. So, my work flow is breaking. How can I change to the next file group, i.e. `fb_table_2018_2` so that is used next?

This is implementation i have done

```
-- archiving the partition greater than 10 month

while exists(
                SELECT fg.name AS fileGroupName, p.partition_number, CONVERT(DATETIME,prv.value) AS partitionValue
                FROM sys.partitions p
                INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
                ON p.object_id = i.object_id AND p.index_id = i.index_id
                INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes ps
                ON ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
                INNER JOIN sys.partition_functions pf
                ON ps.function_id = pf.function_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.partition_range_values prv
                ON pf.function_id = prv.function_id AND p.partition_number = prv.boundary_id
                INNER JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces dds
                ON dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id AND dds.destination_id = p.partition_number
                INNER JOIN sys.filegroups fg
                ON dds.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
                INNER JOIN (SELECT container_id,SUM(total_pages) as total_pages FROM sys.allocation_units GROUP BY container_id)au
                ON au.container_id = p.partition_id
                WHERE i.index_id < 2 AND p.object_id = object_id('dbo.FastLog') AND DATEDIFF(mm,CONVERT(DATETIME,prv.value),getdate()) > 10)
    BEGIN

ALTER PARTITION SCHEME ps_table_Archive NEXT USED [fg_table_2018_1]
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pf_table_Archive()
SPLIT RANGE ('2018-01-01 00:00:00.000')
ALTER TABLE dbo.[table] SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO dbo.[table_Archive] PARTITION 1


ALTER PARTITION SCHEME ps_HDS_FastLog_Archive NEXT USED [fg_HDS_FastLog_2018_2]

    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pf_table_Archive()
    SPLIT RANGE ('2018-02-01 00:00:00.000')


    ALTER TABLE dbo.[table] SWITCH PARTITION 2 TO dbo.[table_Archive] PARTITION 2
    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pf_HDS_FastLog()
    MERGE RANGE ('2018-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    END

    ---creating new partition

    ALTER DATABASE HDS add FILEGROUP [fg_2018_3]

    ALTER DATABASE HDS add FILE ( NAME = N'f_2018_3', FILENAME =N'C:\DATA\f_2018_3.ndf', SIZE = 25600KB ,MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [fg_2018_3]

    ALTER PARTITION SCHEME ps_HDS_FastLog NEXT USED [fg_HDS_FastLog_2018_3]

    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pf_table()
    SPLIT RANGE ('2018-03-01 00:00:00.000')
```

This procedure is run to delete the archived partition and remove the file and file group

```
while exists(
                SELECT fg.name AS fileGroupName, p.partition_number, CONVERT(DATETIME,prv.value) AS partitionValue
                FROM sys.partitions p
                INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
                ON p.object_id = i.object_id AND p.index_id = i.index_id
                INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes ps
                ON ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
                INNER JOIN sys.partition_functions pf
                ON ps.function_id = pf.function_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.partition_range_values prv
                ON pf.function_id = prv.function_id AND p.partition_number = prv.boundary_id
                INNER JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces dds
                ON dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id AND dds.destination_id = p.partition_number
                INNER JOIN sys.filegroups fg
                ON dds.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
                INNER JOIN (SELECT container_id,SUM(total_pages) as total_pages FROM sys.allocation_units GROUP BY container_id)au
                ON au.container_id = p.partition_id
                WHERE i.index_id < 2 AND p.object_id = object_id('dbo.table') AND DATEDIFF(mm,CONVERT(DATETIME,prv.value),getdate()) > 10)
    BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_Staging]
    (
        [Id] [uniqueidentifier]  ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
        [FromTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [column3] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    ) ON [ps_table_Archive]([FromTime])

    CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [uq_cdx_table_Staging] ON [dbo].[table_Staging]
    (
        [FromTime] ASC

    ) ON [ps_table_Archive]([FromTime])

    ALTER TABLE dbo.[table_Archive] SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO dbo.[table_Staging] PARTITION 1
    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pf_table_Archive()
    MERGE RANGE ('2018-03-01 00:00:00.000')

    DROP TABLE dbo.[table_Staging] --Drop old partition data as per retention policy

    end

    alter database test remove file f_2018_1
    alter database test remove filegroup  [fg_2018_1]
```

Both procedure are executed inside a  monthly  scheduled job.

Comment: There looks to be an error in your archive and partition maintenance script. Add that script to your question if you need help fixing it (as code text instead of image). Is your expected result for the scheme to have filegroups `PRIMARY`, `fg_table_2018_2`, `fg_table_2018_3`, `fg_table_2018_4`, `fg_table_2018_5` so that you can drop `fg_table_2018_1`?

Comment: i have added the code..yes after dropping the fg_table_2018_1 ,i need to have the schema with primary,fg_table_2018_2,fg_table_2018_3,fg_table_2018_4,fg_table_2018_5